ADF Snowflake Connector - Key pair authentication - Failed to parse PEM block containing the private key
I have created RSA key pair for my snowflake service account.
I tested authenticating snowflake with this RSA keys in python. Data from snowflake loaded successfully.
Now I'm trying to use this RSA private key for authentication in ADF.
I have followed step by step procedure from this documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-snowflake?tabs=data-factory#key-pair-authentication
But my Privatekey is not working in the snowflake connector.
Added newline characters (\n) to each line in the privatekey file as per above documentation.
key pair authentication
Getting this error - Failed to parse PEM block containing the private key.
Error
Tried in all the ways like - adding newline char (\n), removing newline char, removing header (-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----) & footer (-----END PRIVATE KEY-----) of private key.. nothing worked.
Can anyone please help me on this.

I have checked for special characters in my key.
I have only + / = in my key.
One new thing I found now is ...
I gave the private key as just 'abcd'. still it is showing same error - Failed to parse PEM block containing the private key.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

For reference this is my private key
https://learn-attachment.microsoft.com/api/attachments/aa2ead1a-8d7c-4699-8031-f8f5f3e8767a?platform=QnA

No replies, comments from stackoverflow.
Got solved from microsoft Q&A
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1659093/adf-snowflake-connector-key-pair-authentication-fa

It's great to hear that you were able to resolve your issue. Could you please document your solution in an answer? It would provide clarity for those encountering similar technical challenges within the community.
